# Cross methods timeout for remote service asynchronous call

Tags: c#, wcf

My code has two main methods which **sends tasks** to remote (in another process) services for execution, and **acknowledge success or failure**.

Each task has few steps so it the method AcknowledgeStepComplete **must be called several times** with this given task (asynchronously).

```
public void AcknowledgeStepComplete(CollectionTask task)
{
...
}


public void AcknowledgeStepError(CollectionTask task, Exception exception)
{
...
}

public class CollectionTask : ICoordinationTask
{
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

When sending a task step for execution, i want to know if any call to one of these two methods were received, within a given time frame (i.e. step timeout).

**if not** - invoke the AcknowledgeStepError myself 
(otherwise - do nothing).

How can i check this condition, and invoke only if the given condition is met?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Yossi, can you please add a sample code of the execution of the asyncrounous call to the remote service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe adding this fucnionality to CollectionTask will do the trick 
(the syntax is not perfect but the general idea exists):

```
public class CollectionTask : ICoordinationTask
{
    private Timer _taskInternalTimer;

    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
    public event TaskTimedOutEventHandler TaskTimedOut;

    public CollectionTask ()
    {
         _taskInternalTimer = new Timer();
         _taskInternalTimer.Elapsed += OnTaskInternalTimerElapsed;
         _taskInternalTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTaskInternalTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedArgs args)
    {
        if (_taskInternalTimer.TotalMilisecond >= Timeout)
              TaskTimedOut(this, new TaskTimedOutEventArgs());
    }
}
```

And use it that way:

*in the scope of the CollectionTask instance creation*

```
var task = new CollectionTask();
task.TaskTimedOut += OnTaskTimedOut
```

*the event handle method*

```
 private void OnTaskTimedOut(object sender, TaskTimedOutEventArgs args)
 {
       AcknowledgeStepError(args.Task, new Exception())
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question perfectly, but I'll give it a shot..

From my understanding of the question CollectionTask has some property that defines the expiration time of the task.

Something like this:

```
public class CollectionTask
{
   ...
   public DateTime TaskTimeout;
}
```

You can define a delegate which will be called each time you enter AcknowledgeComplete

```
public void AcknowledgeComplete(CollectionTask task)
{
    if (AcknowledgeCompleteStarted != null)
             AcknowledgeCompleteStarted(this, new AcknowledgeCompleteStartedEventArgs(task))
    ....
    ....
}
```

That way when you enter the method you just notify to some object that was registered to AcknowledgeCompleteStarted event that this event happened, and in the registered method you will be able to run any logic that you desire, such as checking if the task has reached its time out and if so activate AcknowledgeError with an appropriate exception.

it seems that it can be much simpler just by doing:

```
public void AcknowledgeComplete(CollectionTask task)
{
    if (task.Timeout < DateTime.Now)
         AcknowledgeError(task, new Exception());
    ....
    ....
}
```

but i'm pretty sure that was not where you were getting at in your question. 
If I didn't hit the target of the question feel free to elaborate with some more code examples..

Guy

Comment: Timeout must be TimeSpan.. as for your suggestion, it is close to what i was looking for. except one (major) thing - in case AcknowledgeComplete didn't receive a call at all, we should still invoke AcknowledgeError